# PCL: SACSegmentationFromNormals not working

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, ransac

I have a problem with PCL structure SACSegmentationFromNormals. I want to do a cylinder segmentation with C++. A similar plane segmentation worked just fine, but here I get the error message:

"PCL::SACSegmentationFromNormals::initSACModell Input data  not given! Cannot continue."

I am using the PointXYZRGBA and pcl::Normals though. Has anyone an idea? Here is my code so far:

```
 `pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr ProMaTFC::fitting() {

 ...

 pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
 pcl::SACSegmentationFromNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGBA, pcl::Normal> seg;
 seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
 seg.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_CYLINDER);
 seg.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
 seg.setDistanceThreshold(0.1);
 seg.setInputCloud(cloud->makeShared());
 seg.setRadiusLimits(0, 5);
 pcl::PointIndices inlierIndices;
 segmentation.segment(inlierIndices, *coefficients_cylinder);

 ...
 return coefficients_cylinder;
 }`
```

Im using the following libraries (if your wondering):

```
`#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h> 
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h> 
#include <pcl/point_types.h> 
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>   
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h> 
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h> 
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h> 
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h> 
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h> `
```

Comment: Please, avoid posting relevant details as comments, edit your question instead to add information.

Answer (score 1):

you should call the function `setInputNormals()` if you want to use normal information to estimate parameters.